# I need my Ubuntu 22.04 Profiles to lock after 20 unsuccessful attempts for a duration of 15 minutes

Tags: 22.04, login

If someone would be able to assist me in how to go about locking an Ubuntu 22.04 profile after 20 unsuccessful login attempts for a duration of 15 minutes with steps, that would be wonderful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is an "Ubuntu profile"?

Answer (score 6):

The method to utilize this is via PAM, and specifically the faillock module. Here's how I made it work on mine (albeit I'm running 23.04, but I did check that the same module exists on 22.04):

1. Open a terminal
2. Make a backup of the file `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` for instance with issuing a command

```
sudo cp /etc/pam.d/common-auth /etc/pam.d/common-auth.original
```

3. Open the file `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` in your favourite editor (and don't forget to use `sudo`!)
4. As the first line right after `# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)` add

```
auth    required            pam_faillock.so preauth audit deny=20 unlock_time=900
```

5. As first two lines right after `# here's the fallback if no module succeeds` add

```
auth    [default=die]           pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=20 unlock_time=900
auth    sufficient              pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=20 unlock_time=900
```

If you want to add a period during which the failed attempts are counted, the `fail_interval=60` option will set a period of one (1) minute.

In my testing, I set the deny value to three (3) failed attempts and the unlock_time to 20 seconds , and after the required failed attempts I saw the following:

```
[18:50:59] /home/jaska/> su jjo
The account is locked due to 3 failed logins.
(1 minute left to unlock)
```

Hope this helps, further reading on the module: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/pam_faillock.8.html

https://kifarunix.com/lock-linux-user-account-after-multiple-failed-login-attempts/